# Valgrind's behaviour for structs + unions

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a big C-project and thanks to valgrind I cleaned up some mess I was doing with a memory management. I cleaned up everything except for one thing, and after a week of analysis I'm starting to think that that's valgrind's misunderstanding of my code, rather than my mistake. The program is running for good, but that means nothing (I've seen the case when the program runs for good for weeks and then stucks because of 31th flipped bit in an int).

My code uses the next idea: there's the a storage (in terms of my project a "warehouse"), which holds all the kinds of structures I desired to build. I use the trick from the Xlib to keep this as small as possible in memory:

```
 typedef struct
 {
     // data
 } TypeA

 typedef struct
 {
     // data
 } TypeB

 typedef struct
 {
     // data
 } TypeC

 typedef union
 {
    TypeA typea;
    TypeB typeb;
    TypeC typec;
 } UniType;

 typedef struct
 {
     int type;
     UniType data;
 } Element;
```

Then I create an element:

```
SmlErrors SmlWhsAdd(SmlElement element, SmlIndex * index)
{
    SML_CHECKPTR(index);

    SmlElement * ptrold = warehouse.elem;

    warehouse.elem      = realloc(warehouse.elem,
                                  (++warehouse.elemcount) * sizeof(SmlElement));
    if (!(warehouse.elem))
    {
        warehouse.elem = ptrold;
        *index         = 0;
        warehouse.elemcount--;
        return SML_ERR_BADALLOC;
    }

    warehouse.elem[warehouse.elemcount - 1] = element;

    *index = (warehouse.elemcount - 1);

    return SML_ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

*For those, who thinks that ptr = realloc(ptr... is bad - look closer, I save the old one and restore it after. I'm planning to replace all alloc tools with myalloc to crash the program there instead of continuing work*

This code is clear, valgrind is silent. Except for one case. One of my "TypeX" structures (if to be exact, child-of-child-of-TypeX) contains an array:

```
SmlIndex     sprite[SML_THEMEBLOCK_SIZE];
```

Every sprite is also an index from warehouse, so it's mobiles in mobile, as that array is a part of one of the element of that warehouse (in the house that Jack built).

I use the aforementioned function to write the value inside of one of the sprites:

```
SML_CHECKLOC(SmlImageCreate(&(widget->sprite[i]),
                            widget->geometry.size));
// Which calls `WhsAdd` with `&(widget->sprite[i]` as `index`-parameter.
```

And every time I call it this way the valgrind is whining about `Invalid write of size 4`. Every time I'm trying to use the value from `sprite[x]` after that - `Invalid read of size 4`. If to be exact, it's whining about the following line:

```
*index = (warehouse.elemcount - 1);
```

My system is 32bit, SmlIndex is uint32_t

Please, give me a clue about where to dig. After a week of research I'm out of ideas. That's why I'm started to think that that might be valgrind's bug - I also 've heard that it's working strange with unions and structs in it.

One more thing.

```
widget->sprite[i] = 0; // No complainings.
SmlImageCreate(&(widget->sprite[i], ...) // Complainings.
```

Can someone give me a hand, please? I'm drowning in that swamp. Any suggestions about where to look. Anything.

*UPD*:
MCVE: http://pastebin.com/r5T5ZBPC

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: include the exact and complete output of valgrind. Also it would be a huge help if you could create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are heaps of unknowns in what you have posted so far -- you could be messing up memory allocation for just about anything.

Comment: complaining about `*index = (warehouse.elemcount - 1);` suggests the problem is with `*index`, not with `sprite[i]` as you seem to be focusing on. . Make sure that `index` is pointing to allocated memory.

Comment: M.M, index is sprite[0], as I claimed earlier. The full valgrind's output is as follows:
Invalid write of size 4 in SmlWhsAdd in local/smlwarehouse.c:353
Stack of calls, where &sprite[0] is going inside of WhsAdd,
Then "Address 0x6f31538 is 188,272 bytes inside a block of size 189,280 free'd
Stack of the same calls as earlier, realloc at the first place, pointing to realloc line in the WhsAdd.

You've said about heaps of unknown- I've tried to make MCVE, but failed - can't repeat it in just messing with similar situations and structs/unions.

What can I do else?

Comment: I find the proposition that Valgrind misunderstands your code to be highly doubtful, because to do so Valgrind would have to try to understand your code in the first place.  It does not.  It simply observes what your code *does* with memory at run time.  If it says you perform an invalid read, then it's virtually certain that you do perform an invalid read.

Comment: I also tried to print the pointer's value:
`SmlWidgetSpritesCreate &(warehouse.sprite[i])166531448`
`SmlImageCreate index 166531448`
`SmlWhsAdd index 166531448`
So, the pointer doesn't broke during the run.

Comment: John,  I've located the block, that is suspicious from the valgrind's point of view, but can't get any further. He's telling me that I didn't rightfully allocated the value of index, but it's taken from static array.

Comment: @AlexTiger Can you create a minimal example that reproduces the error?

Comment: A minimal *complete* example, please.  Who knows what all these types are, what code these macros provide, and how, specifically, you end up where you do?  The necessary information is not there.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it in minimal code. I failed at it. I will try another time, but don't expect a success.

Comment: YAY! MCVE: http://pastebin.com/r5T5ZBPC At last I'm able to shorten everything to 100 lines to demonstrate.

Comment: FYI: You may want to use the sanitizers (asan, etc.) available now, which use GCC or Clang to instrument binaries.  They offer mostly the same diagnostics as Valgrind, but the performance and diagnostics are much improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Edit history note: the MCVE originally used uninitialized variables, however after initializing all of those, the problem persists)*

In the MCVE, the issue comes from:

```
SmlWhsAdd(sprite, &(warehouse.elem[window].data.wdg.sprite[0]));
```

The second argument is a pointer into the space allocated by an earlier call to `realloc`.

However, inside the `SmlWhsAdd` function, `realloc` is called on this space, which allocates a new block and frees the old. This leaves the second argument pointing into freed space.

---

To fix this, my suggestion would be to review all uses of `SmlWhsAdd` and avoid passing a pointer which is under `warehouse.elem`.

One option might be to use a temporary variable and then assign the index after the call; another option might be to pass some other information which allows the `SmlWhsAdd` function to compute the location to write the index, after it performs `realloc`; or if the index is always at the end you don't even need to have that parameter at all because the caller can do `warehouse.elemcount-1` after.

Comment: M.M, valgrind is bitching about *index = stuff, not warehouse.elem[...] = stuff.

Comment: Braces doesn't work in my gcc, nullified instead: http://pastebin.com/GqenXUi2 Still complainings.

Comment: just a reminder, gen&wdg are in union, init of one thing will rewrite another.

Comment: Like pulling a rug under your own feet. I can't believe I didn't see this. Honestly OP's entire design smells badly.

Comment: removing old comments relating to uninitilalized variables now

Comment: @M.M, about your upd: There is only one realloc - the increasing of the warehouse's elem. SmlIndex is no pointer, it's just a number - 0, 1, 2, which is *index*.

Comment: @AlexTiger No it is a pointer, that points to memory that gets freed. You dereference it and cause the uninitialized read. Can I ask you, what is the reason behind all those nested structs and unions, why just why...?

Comment: @AlexTiger `SmlIndex * index` means that `index` is a pointer. It holds the address of a memory location.  By giving `&(warehouse.elem[window].data.wdg.sprite[0])` as argument, it means that `index` is pointing at a piece of memory which is inside the `warehouse.elem` . You free that memory location and then write `*index = `, which writes into freed space.

Comment: @M.M, understood now. Thank you.
Works without complainings with temp var. Thank you again.